# INFO snap "mir-libs" has bad plugs or slots after install on Ubuntu core/RPi

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap, raspberrypi, mir

I see this when installing mir-libs snap.

```
localhost:~$ sudo snap install mir-libs --edge
**2017-02-17T05:21:54Z INFO snap "mir-libs" has bad plugs or slots: mir-libs (content slot must have a content attribute set)**
mir-libs (edge) 0.1 from 'canonical' installed
```

But still `mir-libs` is installed. Would the above error cause problems later?

Comment: This is only an informational (see "INFO") message. No, it's not a problem, despite being an unattractive message.

Answer (score 1):

The warning was introduced by [`snapd` pull request #2712](https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/pull/2712).

The `content` interface is intended to allow one snap package to share files with a second snap package.  This is only useful if the snap on the receiving side gets the files it was expecting (i.e. if the app expected to get the Mir client library, it probably won't work if it instead receives something else).

To help with this, plugs and slots using this interface can be annotated with a `content` attribute: if the value of this attribute matches, then a connection can be made.  Otherwise, it will fail.  Prior to the above pull request the attribute was optional, and in future it will probably be mandatory.  The warning is in there to encourage people to add the attribute if it is missing.

The `mir-libs` snap (as of revision 24) doesn't appear to include the attribute:

```
$ cat /snap/mir-libs/current/meta/snap.yaml
...
slots:
  mir-libs:
    interface: content
    read:
    - usr/lib
```

So the warning is telling the author of that snap that they need to fix this.  If you are developing a snap that plugs into `mir-libs`, you will need to wait for the `mir-libs` snap to be fixed first (since you won't know what they'll set the attribute to).